# How to create node after other specific Node in XSLT 3

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

I'm currently trying to create a XSL Script that would create a Node (Production) before the Node (Release) and keep the format of the other nodes. Currently my Script is printing the Node (Production) with all the correct information I need but it is creating the node on the place of my Node (Device) by pushing it to the side, as you can see below:

Current result:

```
<launcher>
    <configs>
        <!-- CREATES PRODUCTION NODE SMASHED WITH THE DEVICE NODE -->
        <config name="ALBA_production" extension="ALBA" version="" stage="PRODUCTION"><title>ALBA (Production)</title></config><config name="ALBA" extends="ALBA" abstract="true">
            <param name="deviceName">ALBA</param>
        </config>
        <config name="ALBA_release" extends="ALBA" version="${releaseSITEVersion}">
            <title>ALBA (Release)</title>           
        </config>
        <config name="ALBA_test" extends="ALBA" version="${testSITEVersion5227}">
            <title>ALBA (Test)</title>      
        </config>
        <!-- MANY MORE NODES AFTER THIS ONE -->
    </configs>
</launcher>
```

I need this **(Production) Node to be after the (Device) Node but before the (Release) Node**, as seen here:

```
<launcher>
    <configs>
        <config name="ALBA" extends="ALBA" abstract="true">
            <param name="deviceName">ALBA</param>
        </config>
        
        <!-- CREATES PRODUCTION NODE HERE -->
        <config name="ALBA_production" extension="ALBA" version="" stage="PRODUCTION">
            <title>ALBA (Production)</title>
        </config>
        <!-- -->
        
        <config name="ALBA_release" extends="ALBA" version="${releaseSITEVersion}">
            <title>ALBA (Release)</title>           
        </config>
        <config name="ALBA_test" extends="ALBA" version="${testSITEVersion5227}">
            <title>ALBA (Test)</title>      
        </config>
        <!-- MANY MORE NODES AFTER THIS ONE -->
    </configs>
</launcher>
```

This is my current input File (XML) (consider that there will be more blocks of nodes that follow the same structure that I've just shown):

```
<launcher>
    <configs>
        <config name="ALBA" extends="ALBA" abstract="true">
            <param name="deviceName">ALBA</param>
        </config>
        <!-- CREATES PRODUCTION NODE HERE -->
        <config name="ALBA_release" extends="ALBA" version="${releaseSITEVersion}">
            <title>ALBA (Release)</title>           
        </config>
        <config name="ALBA_test" extends="ALBA" version="${testSITEVersion5227}">
            <title>ALBA (Test)</title>      
        </config>
        <!-- MANY MORE NODES AFTER THIS ONE -->
    </configs>
</launcher>
```

And finally but never the less my current code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
        indent="no" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="config">
        <xsl:variable name="namePrefix"
            select="replace(replace(@name, '_release', ''), '_test', '')" />
        <xsl:if
            test="count(. | //configs/config[contains(@name, $namePrefix)][1]) &lt;= 1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."
                mode="create_production">
                <xsl:with-param name="productionName"
                    select="concat($namePrefix, '_production')" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="config" mode="create_production">
        <xsl:param name="productionName" />
        <xsl:variable name="versionspec" select="@version" />
        <xsl:variable name="extensionspec" select="@extends" />
        <xsl:if test="not(../config[@name=$productionName])">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of
                    select="$productionName" /></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="extension"><xsl:value-of
                    select="$extensionspec" /></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="version"><xsl:value-of
                    select="$versionspec" /></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="stage">PRODUCTION</xsl:attribute>
                <title>
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="replace($productionName, '_production', ' (Production)')" />
                </title>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As I mentioned before my code is outputting the right node but only in the wrong position, that is what I need to know how to solve. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does many more nodes mean, nodes that you also need to find and where you need to add/insert a new element or just nodes that need to be copied through?

Comment: @MartinHonnen they are nodes similar to the three I showed on my input file, the difference is that their device name (their first node) will be ALBA_2, ALBA_3... and so on, they also have release and test nodes. My code already loops and creates one Production node for each one of them, I just need to solve the position problem

Comment: That looks like an odd approach, if there is a pattern to identify your nodes I would suggest to use e.g. `<xsl:template match="configs"><xsl:copy><xsl:for-each-group select="config" group-starting-with="config[matches(@name, '^ALBA(_[0-9]+)?$')]"><xsl:copy-of select="."/><!-- create production nodes here --></xsl:copy-of select="tail(current-group())"/></xsl:for-each-group></xsl:template>`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Oh I cannot use for-each, my boss is a xsl purist, he says xsl is no procedural language and you shoud never use it (which I find stupid) but he doesn't want me using it, that's why the weird work around. Also I have to to the checking because sometimes a block of nodes (Ex. ALBA_2) might already have (Production) in it. That code is working for me I just need to fix the positioning.

Comment: I did suggest to use `for-each-group`, not `for-each`. But good luck with your struggle and your boss.

Comment: You clearly need to do some work on educating your boss. We teach beginners to think twice before using `xsl:for-each` as a kind of universal solution to all problems, but advanced users know that used correctly, it's very often the right tool for the job.

Comment: @MichaelKay I do agree with you and my original code I used for-each. But being on probation period and having my boss already not happy with me for using for-each, trying to educate him sounds a bit far fetch, at least right now but for now I'm just trying to solve the positioning issue, would you have any suggestions? I'm really struggling with this

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the problem, so I'm posting a comment instead of an answer. It looks like you are creating a new "Production" `config` based on an existing `config` which is the first `config` in the document which has a particular prefix. In the example data you posted, that's a "device" config. Your template FIRST creates the Production `config` and THEN copies the original (`<xsl:copy-of select="." />`), but if you want the original (device) config to come first then the `xsl:copy-of` should be the FIRST child of your `<xsl:template match="config">`, not the last child.

Comment: I noticed that in your same data, the "device" `config` has no `version` attribute, so your new "production" `config` has an empty `version`. Is the "device" `config` really the `config` element you want to use?

Comment: @ConalTuohy gosh I feel really stupid now. But thanks your first comment was correct and solved my problem!

Comment: @ConalTuohy you can post it as the answer of my question and I'll accept it ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are creating a new "Production" `config` based on an existing `config` which is the first `config` in the document which has a particular prefix. In the example data you posted, that's a "device" `config`. Your template FIRST creates the Production `config` and THEN copies the original (`<xsl:copy-of select="." />`), but if you want the original (device) `config` to come first then the `xsl:copy-o`f should be the FIRST child of your `<xsl:template match="config">`, not the last child.